# what is @*android:bool/xyz in android

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android

I understand that if we are using

```
@+id/xyz
```

we are adding new resource id to our namespace which can be referenced later. But what exactly

```
@*android:bool/xyz
```

Does that mean adding new boolean to resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@*android:bool/xyz is a reference to a framework-private boolean resource xyz.

You should never use framework-private resources in your app, as they are not public or stable and may not exist on a given device or OS version.